# Cómo hacer que un TextField sea tipo DATE para guardar la fecha en MySQL y trabajar con ella en Java

Tags: java, mysql, date

En mi programa tengo un campo para que el cliente ingrese una Fecha, según MySQL, el formato debe ser: YYYY-MM-DD

entonces, tengo esto globalmente en mi código:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD");
private Date date;
```

1. Falta algo?.
2. Cómo le aplico eso al TextField para la Fecha en Java?
3. Cuál es la sentencia para enviar esa Fecha y guardarla en MySQL?
4. Cuál es la sentencia para leer la columna tipo DATE para mostrarla en el TextField?

Nunca he usado esto, estoy perdido, cualquier ayuda es bienvenida.

Código de mi JTextField:

```
txtFecha = new JTextField();
txtFecha.setColumns(10);
txtFecha.setBounds(140, 78, 150, 20);
JPanel_ConfiguracionDelEvento.add(txtFecha);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que quieres se hace así:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-M-d");
String fechaParaSQL = df.format(date);
```

Es importante la sintaxis `"yyyy-M-d"` ya que otra te fallará. La documentación indica que se deben quitar los ceros a la izquierda en su caso y con tu formato te iba a dar fallos.

Imaginando que uses un PreparedStatement sería:

```
PreparedStatement pstm;
//Creas tu sentencia poniendo ? en el VALUE
//Imaginando que fuera tu segundo parámetro la fecha se la pasas
pstm.setDate(2, java.sql.Date.valueOf(fechaParaSQL));
```

El TextField lo rellenas de la manera normal seteando el texto con `fechaParaSQL` o si prefieres otro formato te lo creas con otro `DateFormater`.

```
txtFecha.setText(fechaParaSQL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Usa un JFormatedTextField

```
parama01= FechaASql((Date) newapunte.txtFechaActual.getValue()); 

pst.setDate   (1, (java.sql.Date) parama01);

 public java.sql.Date FechaASql(Date fecha) throws ParseException{

                      SimpleDateFormat formato = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                      Date  DatFecha = fecha;
                      String utilFecha = formato.format(DatFecha);

                    java.sql.Date FechaSql=java.sql.Date.valueOf(utilFecha);

                    System.out.println(FechaSql);
                    return FechaSql;
```

}